# How to detect an ambiguous DST overlap in Joda Time?

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, dst

In [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), one can easily use the [`DateTimeZone.isLocalDateTimeGap`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#isLocalDateTimeGap%28org.joda.time.LocalDateTime%29) method to tell if a local date and time is invalid because it falls into the gap created by a spring-forward daylight saving time transition.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime(2013, 3, 10, 2, 0);
boolean inGap = zone.isLocalDateTimeGap(ldt);  // true
```

But how do you detect the fall-back transition?  In other words, if a local date and time could be ambiguous because there is an overlap, how do you *detect* that?  I would expect something like `zone.isLocalDateTimeOverlap`, but it doesn't exist.  If it did, I would use it like so:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime(2013, 11, 3, 1, 0);
boolean overlaps = zone.isLocalDateTimeOverlap(ldt);  // true
```

The Joda-Time documentation is clear that *if* there is an overlap during conversions, it will take the earlier possibility unless told otherwise.  But it doesn't say how to *detect* that behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take advantage of [withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap%28%29)

```
public static boolean isInOverlap(LocalDateTime ldt, DateTimeZone dtz) {
    DateTime dt1 = ldt.toDateTime(dtz).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
    DateTime dt2 = dt1.withLaterOffsetAtOverlap();
    return dt1.getMillis() != dt2.getMillis();
}


public static void test() {
    // CET DST rolls back at 2011-10-30 2:59:59 (+02) to 2011-10-30 2:00:00 (+01)
    final DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID("CET");
    LocalDateTime ldt1 = new LocalDateTime(2011,10,30,1,50,0,0); // not in overlap
    LocalDateTime ldt2 = new LocalDateTime(2011,10,30,2,50,0,0); // in overlap
    System.out.println(ldt1 + " is in overlap? " + isInOverlap(ldt1, dtz)); 
    System.out.println(ldt2 + " is in overlap? " + isInOverlap(ldt2, dtz)); 
}
```